# forward proxy nginx?

Tags: nginx, http, веб-сервер, proxy

У меня крутиться plastic scm на localhost и nginx с доменом my.domain.com. Хочу переходя по ссылке my.domain.com что бы открывался plactic на порту 80. Я сделал конфиг в sites-enabled, но при переходе на my.domain.com не показывает что нужно, подсккажите в чем может быть проблема?

```
server {
listen 80;
root /var/www/my.domaim.com;
server_tokens off;
server_name my.domaim.com;
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7178;
}
location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    alias /var/lib/dehydrated/;
}
}  

server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name my.domaim.com;
ssl_certificate /etc/dehydrated/certs/my.domaim.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/dehydrated/certs/my.domaim.com/privkey.pem;
}
```

Comment: А где во втором блоке проксирование?

Comment: Нету, я не в курсе что оно там должно быть(

Comment: На какой адрес нужно сделать проксирование во втором блоке, на тот же локалхост ?

Comment: что не работает то? что показывает?

Comment: @offline поменяйте логику местами. Логика должна быть на сервере с 443, а 80 должен переадресовывать

Comment: @eri не работает прокси, при переходе по my.domain.com не грузиться сервис который на localhost. Показывает ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: фаервол проверял?

Comment: DNS точно правильно настроен?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задача решилась следующим образом:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/my.domain.com;
    server_tokens off;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name my.domain.com;
    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7178;
    }

    location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        alias /var/lib/dehydrated/;
    }

}
server {
      listen 443 ssl;
      server_name my.domain.com;
      ssl_certificate     /etc/dehydrated/certs/deb- 
      my.domain.com/fullchain.pem;
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/dehydrated/certs/deb- 
      my.domain.com/privkey.pem;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

тут не хватает прокси для https

```
server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name my.domaim.com;
ssl_certificate /etc/dehydrated/certs/my.domaim.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/dehydrated/certs/my.domaim.com/privkey.pem;
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7178;
}

}
```

Comment: Изменил логику. Перенес ее на сервер с 443. Не помогает. Конфиг nginx стандарный, в логах ничего нет.